# DateTime.TryParseExact in c# giving wrong value

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse the following date time "2020-04-07T19:27:42.360Z" using below code.

```
    var timeStamp = "2020-04-07T19:27:42.360Z";
    var requestedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(timeStamp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out requestedDate);
```

However it is returing 08-04-2020.
Please help

Comment: What is `2020-04-07T19:27:42` (UTC) in your current time zone? You've put `DateTimeStyles.None` so the result will be a *local* time

Comment: This is UTC. SHould i use adjusttouniversal?

Comment: yes, put `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` and you'll get `2020-04-07T19:27:42 (UTC)`